# Lightning custom connector how to implement sync()

Tags: lightning-connect

I'm trying to understand how custom lightning conponment works

what about if i don't want to override the standard synch() method 
how can i implement the original one to let external objects sync automatically

Please help

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no "original" or "standard" sync method for custom connectors.  Since you can connect with anything at all, there is no way we know how to parse the metadata.

The sync method is invoked when an admin selects "Validate and Sync" on an External Data Source.  For an OData or Salesforce connector, we handle that.  For a custom connector, you have to acquire the metadata and map it to the set of classes that the Apex custom connector framework uses.